# How can I create new shell commands?

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm using bash, and I want to be able to execute a script just by typing its name as a command, same as `pwd` for example.

Is there a specific directory where I need to save my script to, or any other system files I need to edit to achieve this?

Comment: Put it in $PATH. Thats `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Or, create a shell function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install that script in one of the directories of `$PATH`. Use (`echo $PATH`) to see the directories of `$PATH`

- That means either copy the script to
- Or make a symbolic link to the script inside one of the directories of `$PATH`
- Or  append the script directory to `$PATH`

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:<script directory>
  ```

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys, appreciate it. All really helpful info.

Answer (score 3):

You can check what locations are currently checked for direct commands by looking at the `$PATH` variable:

```
echo $PATH
```

It's likely this includes `/usr/local/bin`, in which case you could put a symbolic link there:

```
ln -s /opt/mysuperscript /usr/local/bin/mysuperscript
```

Now you can just type `mysuperscript` to run your script.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to making sure the script is in the $PATH, you also must make the script executable.  `chmod +x SCRIPTNAME` is how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the `ln` command. It can be used to create a link to a file or directory.
Try this link to get more infomation: [ln command example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-ln-command-examples/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.